# Hugh of Saint-Cher's complete Bible commentary (Postillæ in totam Bibliam)?

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, medieval-church, latin, bible-commentary

"Hugh of Saint-Cher († 1263) was the second Dominican Master of Theology in Paris, and the first Dominican cardinal" (n. 39) who, "through the persuasion of Master [St.] Albert [the Great]", convinced "John of Vercelli, Master General of the [Dominican] Order" to accept St. Thomas Aquinas into "the Baccalaureate at the Order’s studium in Paris." ([*William of Tocco’s Life of St. Thomas Aquinas*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=9572) pp. 61-62).

"Hugh is celebrated for his prodigious theological and exegetical works, particularly the monumental commentary on the entire Bible (*Postillæ in totam Bibliam*) that he composed with a team of friars." ([*ibid.*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=9572) p. 62n39).

Does an English translation of Hugh of Saint-Cher's *Postillæ in totam Bibliam* exist?

Comment: St Alphonsus Liguori often made reference to a "Cardinal Hugo" with references of course, in Latin, but (at least in Duties and Dignities of the Priest or Selva), never a specific book reference. Would you say that that "Cardinal Hugo" was the same as the Hugh of Saint-Cher you refer to?

Comment: @I.Chekhov Maybe.